# how to dump the call stack information for native(C/C++) process explicitly when it is not crashed in linux

Tags: android, linux, process

guys:

as you know, in linux/android ,when a process received some SIGs which means the process occurred crash , such as page fault, segment fault ,etc, then for these signals, the default behavior from system will first dump the core information, including the call stack information, and then remove the process.

but sometime, though my program is not crashed, it actually already run abnormally and is not what i expected. then i want to know exactly which code now it is running, so i want to manually dump the call stack information for it. then how to do? manually send the segment fault signal to it? or else ....?

anyone can share the experience ?

thx a lot in advance .

Comment: Well, if you want simple, crude, and probably effective, de-referencing a NULL pointer would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Throw an exception and catch it immediately. I'm not familiar enough with C but in java this would look like this:

```
try {
    throw new RuntimeException("bla bla");
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: From the title, it seems unlikely that what is desired is a java (well, Dalvik) virtual machine's stack trace.  Rather the actual native call stack of the arm (or whatever) processor is what is desired.  This is a bit harder to sort out for an ARM target than for many others, so it may be desirable to let Android's built-in native crash logging capability do the hard work.

Comment: ah, sorry for that. I vaguely remembered it's about C since I did read the title yesterday, but today I only looked at the text and the tags. so you think even the corresponding thing in C is not what he wants?

Comment: C doesn't have Exceptions.  C++ does, but only as an ugly hack (a particularly ugly and optional one on Android) and so using them only to cause a stack dump seems a bit roundabout.